No crea index.html cuando hago el comando ng build --configuration=production
Cuando hago el comando este no me crea el index en dist, en angular.json tengo bien el output
"outputPath": "dist/campus-ride",
"index": "src/index.html",
"browser": "src/main.ts" 

de manera local, todo funciona perfectamente pero no he podido desplegar
